# Mpdf, block absolute positioning is not working

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf, absolute

i want to position my block using absolute, but it for some reason stays in the same place, no matter of left/top attributes. 
Here is my php:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$data = "";
$data .= "<div id='logo'> <img src='logo.png' /> <div id='cv'>CV</div></div>";
```

css:

```
#cv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    color: green;
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FIsm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've found mPDF supports absolute positioning on top-level block elements only.

Adjust your HTML mark-up to the following and your absolute-positioning will begin working:

```
$data .= "<div id='logo'><img src='logo.png' /></div><div id='cv'>CV</div>";
```